# Set template in XML layout file based on URL

Tags: magento-1.7, layout

I have the following lines in an XML layout file to set a blank template for the `product_list` block (we do this to hide the product listing on some anchor categories):

```
<reference name="product_list">
  <action method="setTemplate">
    <template>dummy/dummy/blank.phtml</template>
  </action>
</reference>
```

But I only want the above code to run if `?viewall=1` is not set in the URL.

How can I implement this conditionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement in the question is not achievable via layout xml file. You need to create a module to achieve this. I will show you how you can dynamically change the block template using an event observer.

You need to observe to the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after`. This event will get fired after every layout blocks get generated. So it is the perfect place to do customization.

Module activation file is shown below.

File : `app\etc\modules\Magento_Study.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magento_Study>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magento_Study>
    </modules>
</config>
```

File : `app\code\local\Magento\Study\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magento_Study>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Magento_Study>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <magento_study>
                <class>Magento_Study_Model</class>
            </magento_study>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
                <observers>
                    <change_product_list_template>
                        <class>magento_study/observer</class>
                        <method>changeProductListTemplate</method>
                    </change_product_list_template>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Here we are registering our event in the frontend section. Now define the observer.

File : `app\code\local\Magento\Study\Model\Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Magento_Study_Model_Observer
{
    const BLANK_TEMPLATE = 'dummy/dummy/blank.phtml';

    public function changeProductListTemplate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //get layout object from event
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        //make sure it is a category page
        if (Mage::registry('current_category')) { 

            //check whether current url holds `?viewall=1` term in it.
            $currentUrl = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
            if (strpos($currentUrl, '?viewall=1') !== false) {

                //changing template
                $layout->getBlock('product_list')
                    ->setTemplate(self::BLANK_TEMPLATE);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here first we are make sureing we are in the category page. Next we are checking current url has `?viewall=1` term in it. If yes, we are dynamically changing the template. That's it.

Now clear your cache and reload the page again. Magic happens for sure :)

Comment: ,It will better to use `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('viewall') `for getting` param value`

Comment: @AmitBera yes you are right. I put the helper method intentionally. First you used above method in your answer. So I though showing another approach would be nice. Second my approach will work as long as the url holds  `?viewall=1` irrespective of that term is a parameter or anything else.  I agree the above approach is recommendable one. :)

Comment: Good work. i really impressed you.  :)

Answer (score 1):

In this,

- create a handler on event `controller_action_layout_load_before`.
- On observer create that handler on basic of `viewall` param  value

**Event:** `controller_action_layout_load_before`

**Condition:**  `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('viewall')`  is check page that param have value 1 or  else

So , i am start an observer on basic of this condition which is add new
handler on current layout

When page with

- then add handler `viewall_page_value_is_one` whenever param value is 1
- else create handler name of `viewall_page_value_is_none`

**Observer code:**

```
<?php
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model_Observer{ 
/**
     * Before load layout event handler
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     */
   public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
{
    $Paramsvalue =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('viewall');

    if($Paramsvalue==1):
    $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
       ->addHandle('viewall_page_value_is_one');
       else:
            $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
       ->addHandle('viewall_page_value_is_none');
     endif;
}



}
```

**Config.xml code;**

```
  <global>
        <models>
            <[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
                <class>[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Model</class>
            </[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]>
        </models>
    </global>
       <frontend>
            <events>
                <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                    <observers>
                        <my_current_page_is_observer>
                            <class>[MyCustomModule_Model_Class_Groupname]/observer</class>
                            <method>beforeLoadLayout</method>
                        </my_current_page_is_observer>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_layout_load_before>
         </events>
       </frontend>
```

Depends on **this handler** ,you can set **different template**  `product_list`  block

Also you can do anything layout changes .

```
  <viewall_page_value_is_one>
    <reference name="product_list">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>dummy/dummy/blank.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    </viewall_page_value_is_one>
```

Comment: there are some issue in code now it is fix..

Comment: Observer class name is wrong .. still.. please correct

Comment: +1 for the layout handle approach. this one is recommended if someone need to apply custom template multiple times in multiple place.