# Overriding Product Image on Product Detail without overriding media.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, ce-1.9.2.1, product-view

I am using **magento 1.9.2.1**

I am working on functionality in which I need to change Product Image Dynamically from third Part extension, It can be easily done using `overriding media.phtml` file.

But I am seeking for another method that can override block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media` or something like that can avoid me to change or interact with `.phtml` files.

**EDITED**

Actually, I want to give more about my Question, actually I want to change on Product Detail page without any changes in template section, or without adding or overriding any phtml file.

**please let me know, Is this possible? if yes, then,Iin what way i can do this?**

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the template dynamically. For this you can observe the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` and your observer should somewhat look like this.

```
<?php
class Magento_Study_Model_Observer
{
    const NEW_MEDIA_TEMPALTE = 'your/new/media/template.phtml';

    public function changeProductImageTemplate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        //get layout object from event
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();

        //make sure it is a product page or category page
        if (Mage::registry('current_product') != ''
            || Mage::registry('current_category') != ''
        ) { 

            //changing template
            $layout->getBlock('product.info.media')
                ->setTemplate(self::NEW_MEDIA_TEMPALTE);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are first make sure we are inside a product page. Then we grab the media block and assign a new template to it. Now all you need to do is change the constant `NEW_MEDIA_TEMPLATE` with your custom media template file path and then define that file and do modification there.

To find complete code reference, you can ***[refer this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/83769/3535)***.

### EDIT

This is the layout update xml way of doing this operation

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="product.info.media">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>path/to/your/custom/media.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>

    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.media">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>path/to/your/custom/media.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Comment: thanks @Rajeev K Tomy but I dont want to set any template file for this purpose, I just want to override the block or models, is that possible? what is your view on this?

Comment: @amit_game rewriting should be avoided if an event observer is available to do this. In your question you are saying you want to customize media.phtml file but without touching the original file. The solution to this use this event or use a layout udpate xml file to overwrite the template (I will put this right now as an edit). But if you want to customize the behaviour of the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media`, you need to rewrite that block class

Comment: @amit_game see my edit

Comment: Sorry it may be my fault, but I dont want to use phtml to change my images on Product detail page? is that possible ?

Comment: @amit_game sorry I didnt get you. then what are you trying to achieve then ?

Comment: Actuallly, I want to change my images dynamically on Product detail page but without overriding media.phtml? thats why i am asking is that possible in your view ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29394/discussion-between-amit-game-and-rajeev-k-tomy).